Control specific UVs on a texture map (Reference Vertex Group in Material Nodes)?
I want to do something like setting up a driver on a bone's local rotation to control a UV island's translation on a texture map, I'm having trouble trying to use multiple drivers on multiple UV islands on the same texture map being shared with other stuff that don't move at all.
Here's a video demonstration of what I'm essentially after: https://youtu.be/rxZbH8xeUt8
Is there a method to reference something like a vertex group in a driver expression or material node setup or such? My current node setup for the affected area looks like this:

I'm hoping to avoid having to create several duplicate materials specifically for each segment, though I'm beginning to question which one would be more optimal. If there's a simpler alternative involving 1 dedicated material, that'll be fine.

in my simple example i took a cube, add a vertex group:

left: uv editing
right: cube
Add two empties and a UV warp modifier to your object:

use these settings with your modifier:

if you are moving now your empties, your texture should already react.
Now just add a driver to your bone, so that the bone rotation influences the movement of one empty:
i added this driver to my x-location of one empty:

you might have to adapt this to your settings. Since you didn't provide your blend file, i don't know your settings and you have to check which axis/rotation is right for you.
my shader is pretty simple:

result:

